# Proving theorem with IVT or rolles theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, mean-value-theorem

Assume that $ h : [a,b] → (0,+∞)$ is a positive integrable function and $f : [a, b] →  $ is continuous. Prove that there exists $c ∈ [a, b] $ such that

$\displaystyle\frac{\int_a^b f (x)h(x)dx}{\int_a^bh(x)dx} = f(c)$

assume $f(x)h(x)$ is integrable.

Im assuming I need a theorem such as MVT or IVT to prove this, i used integration by parts, and deduced the left hand side, but it didn't get me anywhere for the proof.

Comment: See “Proof of the first mean value theorem for definite integrals” here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals

Answer (score 0):

Consider $F,H:[a,b]→R$ as $F(x)=∫_a^x[f(t)h(t)dt]$ and $H(x)=∫_a^x[h(t)dt]$. Then both $F$ and $H$ satisfies Cauchy’s MVT, provided $h(x)≠0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Therefore we get at least one $ c $ in $(a,b)$ such that
$$\frac{(F(b)-F(a))}{(H(b)-H(a))} =\frac{(F' (c))}{(H' (c))}$$ that is, $$\frac{(∫_a^b[f(t)h(t)dt])}{(∫_a^b[h(t)dt])}=f(c).$$